# expect returns error "spawn id exp5 not open" running c program

Tags: c, bash, expect

I'am running some test on a program with the following code:

```
set timeout -1
set filename "test"
set programName "./library"

spawn rm -f $filename.db $filename.ind

spawn ./$programName first_fit $filename
expect "Type command and argument/s."
expect "exit"
```

The program output is the following:

```
Type command and argument/s.
exit
```

both lines are written using printf and the next line that executes is fgets();

expects outputs the following error:

```
expect: spawn id exp5 not open
    while executing
"expect "exit""
    (file "add_data_test.sh" line 16)
```

Comment: First comment, if you're launching a program that does not require interactivity, use `exec` instead of `spawn`.

Comment: Next, the library program exited before the 2nd expect command. Before spawning it, add `exp_internal 1` and post the output to your question.